# Node js recursive folder inclusion

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am setting up test automation using yarn, selenium, and node js. In the `wdio.conf.js` file, I must fill in a `specs` array which is an array of strings. These strings are paths of `js` files to execute. I cannot find figure out how to include every single js file in the folder. My structure looks like this

`/specs/productA/`

Within `/productA` there are `.js` files in the root, as well as sub folders, and folders within those sub folders.

`/specs/productA/testCollectionA/`

`/specs/productA/testCollectionB/`

`/specs/productA/testCollectionC/subCollection/`

How can I target every single `js` file in the root, and recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to do using [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).

```
const glob = require("glob")

glob("**/*.js", options, function (error, paths) {
  // `paths` will have your files
})
```

**Edit**: I think the `specs` entry in `wdio.conf.js` actually takes glob syntax. Try using this:

```
specs: [ "tests/**/*.js" ]
```